# Problem with Counters and Cleveref

Tags: hyperref, tcolorbox, counters, cleveref

I like using `amsthm` for my theorems, etc, but to highlight their importance, I like exercises to be in `tcolorbox`es. I want the exercises in the boxes to share the same counter as my theorems.

I managed to create an `exercise` environment which works as desired, harmoniously with `cleveref`:

[image]

But then, it took me a while to realise this, but for some reason, if two exercises in different sections happen to end in the same number (example exercise X.2 from section X and exercise Y.2 from section Y), then doing `\cref{theExercise}` will always point me to the first one (even if I refer to the second one).

Here is an MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

% Theorem Environments
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]   
\newtheorem{definition}[lemma]{Definition}

% Exercise Environment
\makeatletter
\let\c@exercise\c@lemma
\def\p@exercise{\p@lemma}
\def\theexercise{\thelemma}
\makeatother
\crefname{exercise}{exercise}{exercises}
\newenvironment{exercise}[1][]{
    \refstepcounter{exercise}\par\medskip
    \begin{tcolorbox}[breakable, enhanced, colback=gray!7!white, parbox=false, drop fuzzy shadow]
        \noindent {\textbf{Exercise~\theexercise #1}}
        \rmfamily\par\medskip
    }
    {
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \medskip
}

\begin{document}
    \section{The First Section}

    \begin{definition}[Continuity]
        \label{def:continuity}
        $f\colon A\to B$ is continuous if for all $U \subseteq B$,
        \[\text{$U$ is open in $B$} \implies \text{$f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $A$.} \]
    \end{definition}

    \begin{exercise}
        \label{exercise:continuityEpsilonDelta}
        Let $A\subseteq\mathbf R$. Show that $f\colon A\to\mathbf R$ is continuous in the sense of \cref{def:continuity} if and only if for all $a\in A$,  
        \[(\forall\epsilon > 0)(\exists\delta>0)(\forall x\in A)(0<|a-x|<\delta\implies |f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon). \]
    \end{exercise}

     {\bfseries Notice here \verb|\theexercise| is \theexercise.}

    \section{The Second Section}

    \begin{lemma}[Handshaking Lemma]
        \label{lemma:HS}
        Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph. Then
        \[\sum_{v\in V} \deg(v) = 2|E|. \]
    \end{lemma}

    \begin{exercise}
        \label{exercise:HS}
        Prove that if $H=(V,E)$ is a hypergraph, then
        \[\sum_{v\in V}\deg(v) = \sum_{e\in E}|e|. \]
        You may use \cref{lemma:HS}.
    \end{exercise}

     {\bfseries Notice here \verb|\theexercise| is \theexercise.}

    \pagebreak 

    \appendix
    \section{Solutions to Exercises}
    The solution to \cref{exercise:HS} is the following.

    \begin{proof}
        \lipsum[1]
    \end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Clicking the link of `\cref{exercise:HS}` in the appendix will take you to the first exercise, even though I reference the second.

I appreciate any assistance with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a proper theorem-like environment. I tried to reproduce the setup you're using, although I don't like it much: the blank space is excessive.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

% Theorem Environments
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]   
\newtheorem{definition}[lemma]{Definition}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{exerciseinner}[lemma]{Exercise}

\newenvironment{exercise}{\exerciseinner\mbox{}\par\bigskip}{\endexerciseinner}
\newcommand{\theexercise}{\theexerciseinner}

% Exercise Environment
\tcolorboxenvironment{exercise}{
  breakable,
   enhanced,
   colback=gray!7!white,
   parbox=false, drop fuzzy shadow
}

\begin{document}
\section{The First Section}

\begin{definition}[Continuity]\label{def:continuity}
$f\colon A\to B$ is continuous if for all $U \subseteq B$,
\[
  \text{$U$ is open in $B$} \implies \text{$f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $A$.}
\]
\end{definition}

\begin{exercise}\label{exercise:continuityEpsilonDelta}
Let $A\subseteq\mathbf R$. Show that $f\colon A\to\mathbf R$ is 
continuous in the sense of \cref{def:continuity} if and only if 
for all $a\in A$,  
\[
  (\forall\epsilon > 0)(\exists\delta>0)
  (\forall x\in A)(0<|a-x|<\delta\implies |f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon).
\]
\end{exercise}

 {\bfseries Notice here \verb|\theexercise| is \theexercise.}

\section{The Second Section}

\begin{lemma}[Handshaking Lemma]\label{lemma:HS}
Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph. Then
\[
  \sum_{v\in V} \deg(v) = 2|E|.
\]
\end{lemma}

\begin{exercise}\label{exercise:HS}
Prove that if $H=(V,E)$ is a hypergraph, then
\[
  \sum_{v\in V}\deg(v) = \sum_{e\in E}|e|.
\]
You may use \cref{lemma:HS}.
\end{exercise}

 {\bfseries Notice here \verb|\theexercise| is \theexercise.}

\pagebreak 

\appendix
\section{Solutions to Exercises}
The solution to \cref{exercise:HS} is the following.

\begin{proof}
\lipsum[1]
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd much prefer `\newtheorem{exercise}[lemma]{Exercise}` (and no `\newenvironment{exercise}`) to get

[image]

Comment: I agree with your stylistic choice. Thank you for this solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the optional argument of `\label` as follows:

`\label[exercise]{exercise:HS}`

This will give you the expected beahviour of the reference in the text.

For a more automated solution, you could use `\crefalias` as shown in the following modified version of your exercise environment.

```
\newenvironment{exercise}[1][]{\crefalias{lemma}{exercise}
    \refstepcounter{lemma}\par\medskip
    \begin{tcolorbox}[breakable, enhanced, colback=gray!7!white, parbox=false, drop fuzzy shadow]
        \noindent {\textbf{Exercise~\thelemma #1}}
        \rmfamily\par\medskip
    }
    {
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \medskip
}
```

More information on this can be found in chapter "6  Overriding the Cross-Reference Type"  of the `cleveref` manual.